# inner join with pivot condition sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I currently have the following sql query:

```
SELECT  
  name,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(date) = 1, amount, 0) ) AS jan,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(date) = 2, amount, 0) ) AS feb,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(date) = 3, amount, 0) ) AS mar,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(date) = 4, amount, 0) ) AS apr,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(date) = 5, amount, 0) ) AS mei,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(date) = 6, amount, 0) ) AS jun,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(date) = 7, amount, 0) ) AS jul,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(date) = 8, amount, 0) ) AS agu,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(date) = 9, amount, 0) ) AS sep,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(date) = 10, amount, 0) ) AS okt,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(date) = 11, amount, 0) ) AS nov,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(date) = 12, amount, 0) ) AS des,
  SUM( amount ) AS total 
FROM iuran_detail 
WHERE (
  date BETWEEN '$date_first' AND '$date_last'
) GROUP BY name;
```

I want modification with 2 tables sql, user table (along with group) and amount.

[image]

I want to combine the inner join or another way, to get the following result (e.g by group A):

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: If joining tables it is best practice to prefix EVERY column reference with either the source table name OR by an alias given to the source table (I use the latter). **"date" is a terrible column name** as it is also used by SQL itself and can cause confusion, so below I have used the MySQL backticks to reference that column, in SQL-Server you could use `[date]` instead.

```
SELECT  
  u.name,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(`date`) = 1, d.amount, 0) ) AS jan,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(`date`) = 2, d.amount, 0) ) AS feb,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(`date`) = 3, d.amount, 0) ) AS mar,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(`date`) = 4, d.amount, 0) ) AS apr,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(`date`) = 5, d.amount, 0) ) AS mei,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(`date`) = 6, d.amount, 0) ) AS jun,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(`date`) = 7, d.amount, 0) ) AS jul,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(`date`) = 8, d.amount, 0) ) AS agu,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(`date`) = 9, d.amount, 0) ) AS sep,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(`date`) = 10, d.amount, 0) ) AS okt,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(`date`) = 11, d.amount, 0) ) AS nov,
  SUM( IF( MONTH(`date`) = 12, d.amount, 0) ) AS des,
  SUM( d.amount ) AS total 
FROM table_trx d
INNER JOIN table_user u on d.user_id = u.id
WHERE (
  d.`date` BETWEEN '$`date`_first' AND '$`date`_last'
) GROUP BY u.name;
```

Personally I do not like using IF() as an alternative to the more standard CASE expression as it is more broadly supported in SQL databases.

```
SELECT  
  u.name,
  SUM( case when MONTH(`date`) = 1 then d.amount else 0 end ) AS jan,
  SUM( case when MONTH(`date`) = 2 then d.amount else 0 end ) AS feb,
  SUM( case when MONTH(`date`) = 3 then d.amount else 0 end ) AS mar,
  SUM( case when MONTH(`date`) = 4 then d.amount else 0 end ) AS apr,
  SUM( case when MONTH(`date`) = 5 then d.amount else 0 end ) AS mei,
  SUM( case when MONTH(`date`) = 6 then d.amount else 0 end ) AS jun,
  SUM( case when MONTH(`date`) = 7 then d.amount else 0 end ) AS jul,
  SUM( case when MONTH(`date`) = 8 then d.amount else 0 end ) AS agu,
  SUM( case when MONTH(`date`) = 9 then d.amount else 0 end ) AS sep,
  SUM( case when MONTH(`date`) = 10 then d.amount else 0 end ) AS okt,
  SUM( case when MONTH(`date`) = 11 then d.amount else 0 end ) AS nov,
  SUM( case when MONTH(`date`) = 12 then d.amount else 0 end ) AS des,
  SUM( d.amount ) AS total 
FROM table_trx d
INNER JOIN table_user u on d.user_id = u.id
WHERE (
  d.`date` BETWEEN '$`date`_first' AND '$`date`_last'
) GROUP BY u.name;
```